# How can I get current whether? I did some code here but getting stuck at fetch()

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

```
const getWeather = (location) => {
    let url = ''
    let output = ''

    if (isNumeric(location)) {
        url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=${location}&units=imperial${api_key}`
    } else {
        url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${location}&units=imperial${api_key}`
    }

    console.log(url)

    fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data)
            // YOUR CODE GOES HERE (REMOVE THIS ONCE YOU ADD YOUR CODE)
            output += `<h2>Current Weather for ${data.city.name}</h2>
```

I don't know is that that output for title right or something wrong?
I just want to get my current whether. Any helps I appreciate it!

Comment: you need to do something with `output` - for example `console.log(output)` ... it will currently contain the city name of the result

Comment: could you give me more specific about it? I think I did that, it worked, but it doesn't show on my page for detail

Comment: console.log outputs to the browser developer tools console

Comment: Oh I see that, but I want to display it on web page

Comment: Right, I misunderstood the question

Answer (score 0):

As they said above, you need to take the output and pass it tp the html. something like

```
  ` document.querySelector("#myDiv").innertHTML = output
`
```

where myDiv is the id attribute of a div in your HTML
    
        `<div id='myDiv' > </div>`

Comment: it said document.querySelector not a function at whether.js.47

Comment: you either typed it wrong or have a VERY OLD browser - which makes no sense, since you are using fetch

Comment: you can use `document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = output; ` instead

Comment: I don't know what was wrong it shows this Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at weather.js:47

Comment: try to create a global variable (out of getWeather) like `let myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv"); ` abd then, inside getWeather, try to assign it `this.myDiv.innerHTML = output;`

Comment: the important question is, have you created the div with id `myDiv`

Comment: @mauriciodelos - `this.myDiv`??? are you sure? variables created globally using `let` do not work like that